# Upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5 - How to refactor RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, configuration

The following code will not compile after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5. Apparently these two methods (`configureRepositoryRestConfiguration`, `configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener`) have been removed from the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class. I have not been able to find any documentation on what is the 'proper' way of configuring rest controllers in Spring Boot 1.5 via Java. All of the guides I have found on Spring Boot 1.5+ involve XML-based configuration, whereas I would **strongly** prefer to stick with Java-based configuration. How do I refactor this class to be compatible with the 1.5 changes?

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  private static final String BASE_URI = "/rest";
  @Autowired private BeforeCreateSnippetValidator beforeCreateSnippetValidator;
  @Autowired private BeforeCreateModuleValidator beforeCreateModuleValidator;

  @Override
  protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    config.setBasePath(BASE_URI);
    config.exposeIdsFor(Snippet.class, Placement.class, Module.class, Page.class, Position.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", beforeCreateSnippetValidator);
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", beforeCreateModuleValidator);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Finally*** after much guessing, I found the solution. You simply have to change `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` to `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` and change `@Configuration` to `@Component`. This is assuming you have Component scan setup.

```
@Component
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String BASE_URI = "/rest";
  @Autowired private BeforeCreateSnippetValidator beforeCreateSnippetValidator;
  @Autowired private BeforeCreateModuleValidator beforeCreateModuleValidator;

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    config.setBasePath(BASE_URI);
    config.exposeIdsFor(Snippet.class, Placement.class, Module.class, Page.class, Position.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", beforeCreateSnippetValidator);
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", beforeCreateModuleValidator);
  }
}
```